# Getting IndentationError: using Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I have an issue. I am getting the below error while setting my `view.py` page. I am explaining my error below.

```
File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/crud/views.py", line 10
    c = Context({'message': 'Hello world!'})
                                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

My `view.py` file is given below.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, Context
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    t = loader.get_template('index.html')
    c = Context({'message': 'Hello world!'})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove any tabs from your indentaion, and use 4 spaces everywhere. In the code you pasted, you have a tab in the indentation for this line rather than 4 space.

```
t = loader.get_template('index.html')
```

Comment: As a side note: when you get this kind of issues, use tabnanny: `python -mtabnanny path/to/your/module.py`